# Show that the function is continuous on $[-1,1]$

Tags: limits, continuity, solution-verification

$f(x)=\mid{x}\mid$

Let $a\in(-1,1)$

$\mid f(x)-f(a)\mid=\mid\mid x\mid-\mid a\mid\mid\leq\mid x-a\mid$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given and define $\delta=\epsilon$, whenever $\mid x-a\mid<\delta,\space \mid f(x)-f(a)\mid<\epsilon.$

$\therefore f(x)$ is continuous on the interval $(-1,1)$

Also, $\lim_{x\to-1^+}f(x)=1=\lim_{x\to-1}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=1=\lim_{x\to1}f(x)$

$\therefore f(x) $ is continuous on the right side of $-1$ and on the left side of $1$.

Thus, we conclude that $f(x)=\mid x\mid$ is continuous on the interval $[-1,1]$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Seems fine! (Though I'm a little confused by the end of the line that begins 'also' - should that two-sided limit be there?)

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is needed or not.

Comment: I think it should be f(1) and f(-1). For you to be able to use definition of continuity at a point...

Comment: Ahh that makes sense.

Comment: But I did show that $f(x)$ is continuous on the interval $(-1,1)$. Is that not valid as well?

Comment: You can show that f is continuous at every point of the line. So its continuous on [-1,1].

Comment: The problem is with the end points. You have shown that $\lim_{x\to -1^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)$ exist but you also need to write/show that $\lim_{x\to (-1)^+}f(x)=f(-1)$ and $\lim_{x\to (1)^-}f(x)=f(1)$ in order to prove continuity at the end points.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks correct. I would say that you should include words in the proof to explain what's being done.

You can, in fact, prove something a little more general. Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an interval such that $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Then $|f|$ is continuous.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and let $a \in I$ be our point of interest. Then, we wish to prove that:

$$\exists \delta > 0: |x-a| < \delta \implies | |f|(x)-|f|(a) | < \epsilon$$

However, we note that $|f|(x) := |f(x)|$. By the reverse triangle inequality, it is the case that:

$$| |f(x)| - |f(a)| | \leq |f(x)-f(a)|$$

We know that the desired $\delta_1 > 0$ exists when we have:

$$|f(x)-f(a)| < \epsilon$$

So, we simply choose our required $\delta = \delta_1$ and we are done.